# How to disable vim syntax color?

Tags: vim

I am working with an Ubuntu 10.04 VM.  By default, `vim` shows syntax color and I don't want it. I do not have a `.vimrc` file in my home directory (or anywhere in the system for that matter).  I do have a file called `.viminfo` in my home directory but that doesn't seem to be where the setting is because when I rename it, the syntax color is still on.  I also like to have line numbers and for that I created a `.exrc` file in my home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it figured:

`syntax off`

in `.vimrc`

Answer (score 14):

To turn off color syntax highlighting, pres <kbd>ESC</kbd> and type:

```
:syntax off
```

To turn it on again, type:

```
:syntax on
```

To make the changes permanently, you can create `~/.vimrc` file and add the following line:

```
syntax off
```

Comment: but that is just for in the existing instance.  putting it in `.exrc` makes it cross instance

Comment: @amphibient I just edited my answer.